# Test of variance between 2 treatments split in multiple groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, levenes-test

I want to compare the "spread" of the data points in two treatments (blue and green below), so I went for a Levene's test of variance equality.

However, my data consists in 12 subgroups ('X' axis in figure below), each having potentially a different variance.

[image]

In the violin plot, I want to test if the blue group has a different variance than the green group.

So I decided to perform the Levene's test (from Python StatsModels package) after resizing each "violin" like this:

1. subtract with the mean of the corresponding subgroup × treatment;
2. divide both treatments by the standard deviation *of the blue treatment only*, so that each blue distribution has now mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Then I perform the test on the pooled data.

Is this the correct way to do it? Does it make sense? Is it OK, but I should use median and interquartile range instead of mean/std? Would you suggest a better type of analysis, like a linear model that would test for different variances? I haven't found many sources tackling this setup.

P.S.: each 'X' subgroup has the same number of points.